# Does EJB 3.2 / CDI have an equivalent of Spring 4 Meta annotations?

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-7, weld

Does somebody know how to create a "shortcut" for a couple of annotations in CDI?

You know, something called *meta-annotations* in Spring world:

```
@Singleton
@Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED, dontRollbackOn = SomeException.class)
@SomeOtherAnnotations
public @interface MyService {
    // ...
}

@MyService
public class OrderService {
  // ...
}
```

The goal is obvious: just to don't have to specify the same setup in every class. As far as I know, it's not possible in CDI, but does somebody know if EJB 3.2 supports something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDI has the concept of [stereotypes](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#stereotypes) that you can use in your example:

```
@Singleton
@Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED, dontRollbackOn = SomeException.class)
@SomeOtherAnnotations
@Stereotype
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyService {}
```